# Alignment and balancing readout doesn't match required values

Tags: toyota, tires, alignment, wheel-balance

I had gone on a road trip and had hit a bad pothole. The steering started pulling a bit after that. After I got the alignment and balancing done yesterday, the pull seems better, but the values on the sheet don't look encouraging, and I don't know the set values for the vehicle (Toyota Innova 2013). Can someone read this right?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Perhaps the pothole damaged something that can't be corrected, and they missed. presumably the centre column are the recommended settings. I see the vehicle has already been some distance: have you ever had suspension or steering parts replaced? You could always go to another shop, but I don't think any two readings will ever be the same (: depending not only on the equipment but the technician's abililty to set it up correctly.